# VBA Autofilter with variable range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make my autofilter range based on the value of variables, but it isn't working. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
                   Dim y, z As Integer
                   y = 5
                   z = 3

                    rows(z).Select
                    Selection.AutoFilter
                    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Active Worksheet").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
                    **ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Active Worksheet").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add _
                    Key:=Range(Cells(z, y)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
                    :=xlSortNormal**
                    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Active Worksheet").AutoFilter.Sort
                        .Header = xlYes
                        .MatchCase = False
                        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                        .Apply
                    End With
```

Comment: The error is coming up in the portion surrounded by asterisks--thanks!

Comment: What error was it?

Comment: Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Comment: For the Key, try `Worksheets("Active Worksheet").Cells(z,y)` (you need to declare what worksheet the `Range` and `Cells` is to be on).  You can't (AFAIK) do ` Range(Cells())`, you need either `Cells()`, or `Range(Cells(),Cells())`.

Comment: Awesome! I used `Worksheets("Active Worksheet").Cells(z,y)` and that did the trick-- thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue is you're using `Range(Cells())`, which isn't how VBA likes things.  If using a range, you want to do either `Range("A1")`, or `Cells(1,1)`.  If you *need* to use `Range`, then you just do `Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(1,1))`.

So, in your erroring line, change the key to `Key:=Cells(z,y)` or `Range(Cells(z,y),Cells(z,y))`.

However, I also [highly recommend avoiding using `.Select`/`.Active`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros):

```
Sub whatever()
Dim y As Integer, z As Integer
Dim mainWB  As Workbook
Dim activeWS As Worksheet

Set mainWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set activeWS = mainWB.Worksheets("Active Worksheet")

y = 5
z = 3

With activeWS
    .Rows(z).AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Cells(z, y), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With .AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End With
End Sub
```